# Adding file name column to Dask DataFrame

Tags: python, csv, dask, parquet, dask-dataframe

I have a data set of around 400 CSV files containing a time series of multiple variables (my CSV has a time column and then multiple columns of other variables).

My final goal is the choose some variables and plot those 400 time series in a graph.

In order to do so, I tried to use Dask to read the 400 files and then plot them.

However, from my understanding, In order to actually draw 400 time series and not a single appended data frame, I should groupby the data by the file name it came from.

Is there any Dask efficient way to add a column to each CSV so I could later groupby my results?

A parquet files is also an option.

For example, I tried to do something like this:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import os

filenames = ['part0.parquet', 'part1.parquet', 'part2.parquet']
df = dd.read_parquet(filenames, engine='pyarrow')

df = df.assign(file=lambda x: filenames[x.index])

df_grouped = df.groupby('file')
```

I understand that I can use from_delayed() but then I lose al the parallel computation.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are can work with CSV files, then passing [`include_path_column`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_csv.html) option might be sufficient for your purpose:

```py
from dask.dataframe import read_csv
ddf = read_csv("some_path/*.csv", include_path_column="file_path")
print(ddf.columns)
# the list of columns will include `file_path` column
```

There is no equivalent option for `read_parquet`, but something similar can be achieved with `delayed`. Using `delayed` will not remove parallelism, the code just need to make sure that the actual calculation is done after the delayed tasks are defined.